# How to check if 2 email fields have the same value entered during content creation?

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm trying to create a *custom signup* content type and I'm wondering if there is a way to check if two email fields have the same value entered. Similar to typing in an email twice to make sure you have the correct email down.

If the two email fields are not the same an error needs to appear upon saving.

I'm not using a webform for this, it's a custom content type.

Comment: You can do it with the help of form alter and ajax. You just need to alter the form and add for both field and validate field on change event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this question is about D7, you could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and create a (rather basic) rule like so:

- Rules Event: Before saving content
- Rules Conditions:

  - Content is of type "custom signup".
  - Entity has field (related to your 1st eMail field).
  - entity has field (related to your 2nd eMail field).
  - Data comparison: the value of the 1st eMail field is NOT equal to the value of the 2nd eMail field.
- Rules Action: Show a message on the site (of type "error").